# How to write/read std::chrono::zoned_seconds to/from a stream using chrono::parse?

Tags: c++, datetime-format, fstream, c++-chrono, c++23

I am trying to write a `chrono::zoned_seconds` object as text to a file and then retrieve it and construct another `chrono::zoned_seconds` object later. How can this be done in a fairly efficient way?

I don't think the code snippet below shows the correct result:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <print>
#include <chrono>
#include <format>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>


int main()
{
    {
        std::ofstream file("data.txt");
        if (!file) {
            std::println( "Unable to open file.\n" );
            return 1;
        }

        auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        const std::chrono::zoned_seconds zs { "America/New_York", std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::seconds>( now ) };

        std::format_to(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(file), "{:%F %T %Z}", zs);
        std::println( "{:%F %T %Z}", zs ); // correct time
    }

    {
        std::ifstream file("data.txt");
        if (!file) {
            std::println( "Unable to open file.\n" );
            return 1;
        }

        std::string str;
        std::getline(file, str);
        std::istringstream iss { str };

        std::chrono::sys_seconds tp;
        std::string zone_name;
        iss >> std::chrono::parse("%F %T %Z", tp, zone_name);
        std::chrono::zoned_seconds zs { zone_name, tp };
        std::println( "{:%F %T %Z}", zs );  // incorrect time!!
    }
}
```

As can be seen, I used `std::chrono::parse` but the outputs don't match:

```
2024-03-01 13:35:20 EST
2024-03-01 08:35:20 EST
```

Comment: Can you modify your example and show the input file data as an `std::istringstream` and moving your file loading code to a function accepting a `std::istream&`. That way we can compile debug and test your code too, and you can remove all the file handling (valid stream checking) from your example. Benefit for you : you will learn a bit on how to write testable code (that doesn't rely on the filesystem)

Comment: @PepijnKramer I tested [here](https://godbolt.org/z/4zh3bWjPE).

Comment: The obvious next step is to print `str` to deterrmine if the problem is in writing or reading from the file.  Generally you want to test round tripping, serlialization and deserialization all as their own tests.  You have shown a round trip problem (A->B->A): look at the two components.  Hopefully it is in B->A as you suspect.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Printing `iss.str()` shows that the content of the file is as expected. That's why I think the problem is in parsing the `iss`.

Comment: I do not know what you expect, so "as expected" is without meaning.  I could guess what you expect, but I can also guess what the file contains.  I could verify, but again "as expected" doesn't help.  The actual string would help otoh.  Aha, I have a theory now.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont It means that the current time of New York is properly written in the file. So there is probably no problem with serialization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two bugs in your code.  To show them I'm going to read and write from a `stringstream` to enable demos at https://wandbox.org (which does not allow file creation).  However parsing and streaming to `stringstream` is identical to parsing and streaming to `fstream` except for construction/opening of the stream.

Here is your code virtually unchanged, except using `stringstream`:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <print>
#include <chrono>
#include <format>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>


int main()
{
    std::stringstream file;
    auto now = std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
    const std::chrono::zoned_seconds zs { "America/New_York", now };

    file << std::format( "{:%F %T %Z}", zs);
    std::println( "{:%F %T %Z}", zs ); // correct time

    std::chrono::sys_seconds tp;
    std::string zone_name;
    file >> std::chrono::parse("%F %T %Z", tp, zone_name);
    std::chrono::zoned_seconds zs2 { zone_name, tp };
    std::println( "{:%F %T %Z}", zs2 );
}
```

And the [output currently looks like](https://wandbox.org/permlink/clupGZHCh32wSM6X):

```
2024-03-01 14:04:28 EST
2024-03-01 09:04:28 EST
```

The reason for the large discrepancy in time is that when your format a `zoned_time` it displays the **local** time, not UTC.  But when you read it in above, you are parsing as if the time parsed is UTC, not local:

```
    std::chrono::sys_seconds tp;
```

By changing the above line to:

```
    std::chrono::local_seconds tp;
```

you change the semantics of `2024-03-01 14:04:28` from UTC to *local* time.

[Output:](https://wandbox.org/permlink/y07X2zdxUumsicTZ)

```
2024-03-01 14:08:06 EST
2024-03-01 14:08:06 EST
```

Although this looks right, it is still subtly wrong.

`EST` is a IANA time zone with no DST rules.  It has a fixed UTC offset of -5h.  `America/New_York` is the same as `EST` between `sys_days{Sunday[1]/November/y} + 6h` and `sys_days{Sunday[2]/March/(y+1)} + 7h`, and otherwise is on daylight saving with a UTC offset of -4h.  So the program above will only be correct when daylight saving is not in effect for `America/New_York`.

To see this more clearly, replace:

```
auto now = std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
```

with:

```
auto now = sys_days{July/4/2024} + 12h + 0s;
```

I.e. [Let's see how this program behaves in the Summer time.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/j8JjDKClTMkQkgWb)

This line:

```
std::chrono::zoned_seconds zs2 { zone_name, tp };
```

throws a `std::runtime_error` exception because it is trying to locate a time zone named "EDT" and is failing to find it.  [IANA has lots of time zones with an *abbreviation* of "EDT", but none that have that *name*.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

gcc provides a helpful message in the `runtime_error::what()` message:

> what():  tzdb: cannot locate zone: EDT

---

> *Aside:* See [this article](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes#convert_by_timezone_abbreviation) which addresses the difficulties associated with mapping a time zone *abbreviation* to a time zone *name*, and techniques for doing as much as possible.

---

To correct this bug, `"America/New_York"` must be streamed to `file` instead of `"EST"` or `"EDT"`.  This can be fixed by changing one line:

```
file << std::format( "{:%F %T %Z}", zs);
```

to:

```
file << std::format( "{:%F %T }", zs) << zs.get_time_zone()->name();
```

I.e. this outputs the actual time zone *name* as opposed to the time zone *abbreviation*.

[Output:](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lyn9HeMJaFBITNH4)

```
2024-03-01 14:13:30 EST
2024-03-01 14:13:30 EST
```

So now this line:

```
std::chrono::zoned_seconds zs2 { zone_name, tp };
```

is guaranteed to use the same time zone name as was used in this line:

```
const std::chrono::zoned_seconds zs { "America/New_York", now };
```

Here is the complete fixed example for reference:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <print>
#include <chrono>
#include <format>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>


int main()
{
    std::stringstream file;
    auto now = std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
    const std::chrono::zoned_seconds zs { "America/New_York", now };

    file << std::format( "{:%F %T }", zs) << zs.get_time_zone()->name();
    std::println( "{:%F %T %Z}", zs ); // correct time

    std::chrono::local_seconds tp;
    std::string zone_name;
    file >> std::chrono::parse("%F %T %Z", tp, zone_name);
    std::chrono::zoned_seconds zs2 { zone_name, tp };
    std::println( "{:%F %T %Z}", zs2 );
}
```

Comment: Will the abbreviation change to EDT daylight savings is in effect?

Comment: Yes. For example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/B29S3ImQM2QRFaNu

Comment: I am trying to see the correctness error then.  The time is either EDT or EST and gets parsed to the right UTC offset for it.  Just that we might not get American/New York?  Ie, right (universal) time, wrong location.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, passing `std::chrono::sys_seconds` to `parse` makes it do the extra work of changing it to UTC because the system time was in UTC? Whereas  passing `std::chrono::local_seconds` makes it only parse the string as it is without doing any conversion?

Comment: This is what will happen in this case: https://wandbox.org/permlink/j8JjDKClTMkQkgWb. It turns out the `EDT` is not an IANA time zone name.  And in general, the abbreviation (standard or daylight saving) might not be an IANA time zone name.  Also in general, a time zone abbreviation can be used my multiple time zones simultaneously, and sometimes those different time zones will have different DST rules, and even different UTC offsets.  So you just can't depend on abbreviations to identify a time zone.

Comment: See https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes#convert_by_timezone_abbreviation for more information.

Comment: @digito_evo.  Almost right.  `sys_seconds` **is** UTC.  And `local_seconds` **is** local time.  The type system helps you keep these two distinct ideas separate in your code, and even overloads the `zoned_seconds` constructor to maintain the semantics of each.  In this example the magic happens in the `zoned_seconds` constructor, as opposed to within `parse`.

Comment: Additionally:  Every type has a simple readable streaming operator.  So freely stream out to `std::cout` things like `now` and `tp` to easily check the values to aid in debugging and understanding these examples.

Comment: And is there a way to avoid using stringstream here? Any library function that parses the `str` without the need to use <sstream>?

Comment: You can parse straight from a file using the same code.  Just change the type of `file` to `fstream`.  I changed it to `stringstream` only to make the demos easier on the online compilers.  If you mean from character buffers, no.  However character buffers managed by `std::string` can be efficiently moved into and out of `stringstream` in modern C++.  To get faster than std-stream-based parsing you need to write your own.  Efficiency can be gained by reducing flexibility on the format and reducing or eliminating error checking.

Comment: @HowardHinnant I currently don't want to write my own parser. I think I'll try to move the temporary string to `iss` as you mentioned.

Comment: You can even: `file >> std::chrono::parse("%F %T %Z", tp, zone_name);` where `file` is your original `std::ifstream`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    std::chrono::sys_seconds tp;
    std::string zone_name;
    iss >> std::chrono::parse("%F %T %Z", tp, zone_name);
```

this is incorrect.  You are parsing a zoned time H:M:S into a sys_seconds time point.

The resulting time point is a lie.  It is in the wrong time zone - the system time zone.

When you convert the wrong time zone time point to NY, it correctly changes the hour value.

A `std::local_time` is a time without a time zone.  You want to use it instead of `sys_time` there.